# About cron No such file or directory

Tags: magento2, cron

In Magento 2.2

My Magento cron job is as follows

```
* * * * */opt/alt/php71/usr/bin/php /home/XXX/public_html/bin/magento cron:run 2>&1 | grep -v Ran jobs by schedule
```

Due to this cron, so many email came. In 1 minute,  3-5 emails.

about the mail :

```
grep: jobs: No such file or directory
grep: by: No such file or directory
grep: schedule: No such file or directory
```

Anyone know what happened?

Please assist. Thank you

Answer (score 3):

Please update

```
grep -v Ran jobs by schedule
```

to

```
grep -v 'Ran jobs by schedule'
```

Example cron job is as follows

```
* * * * * /usr/bin/php /var/www/magento2/bin/magento cron:run | grep -v "Ran jobs by schedule" >> /var/www/magento2/var/log/magento.cron.log
* * * * * /usr/bin/php /var/www/magento2/update/cron.php >> /var/www/magento2/var/log/update.cron.log
* * * * * /usr/bin/php /var/www/magento2/bin/magento setup:cron:run >> /var/www/magento2/var/log/setup.cron.log
```